# Dual-boot Kali and Windows 10: How can I add Windows 10 to GRUB? (GRUB and UEFI acting weirdly)

Tags: grub, kali-linux

After installing Kali to dual-boot it and Win10, I was briefly unable to access Kali since UEFI wouldn't detect it:

- After a couple of fixes, I received boot error: `Invalid partition table!` 
   I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> upon seeing it and text saying something about the GRUB bootloader appears, however it vanishes too fast to read anything else; GRUB appears afterward with only a Kali entry
- I can still access Windows 10 via the one-time <kbd>F12</kbd> boot menu, selecting UEFI HDD to boot Win 10 as it would normally

How can I add a Windows entry to GRUB so that I don't have to enter UEFI every time, as I've tried:

- `sudo os-prober` after mounting my Windows 10 partition (yields no results)
- Adding an entry manually by editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` (no results as well)
- `sudo update-grub` after both, but it only created some Kali files

Comment: In order to use Grub both OSes must be installed in the same mode UEFI or Legacy/"BIOS".

Comment: More precisely, the variant of grub and Windows Boot Manager you use need to be of the same mode. (Often you can replace either of them with `grub-install` or `bcdboot`.)